# Java StringBuilder.append doesn't remove escape characters

Tags: java, escaping, character, stringbuilder

I'm trying to append the literal string `"\F\"` to a StringBuilder object.  I declare the replacement string as a String variable using the escape characters as such:

```
String replace = "\\F\\";
```

When I append the variable replace to my StringBuilder object I get escape characters in the resulting string.  For example:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("This is the string I will be appending to.");
String replace = "\\F\\";
builder.append(replace);
String newString = builder.toString();
```

The resulting value of newString is `"This is the string I will be appending to.\\F\\"`.  I want the value of newString to be `"This is the string I will be appending to.\F\"`.

On a side note, when I execute

```
System.out.println(replace);
```

the system correctly removes the escape characters resulting in `"\F\"` on the console.

Apologies in advance if this is answered elsewhere.  I searched extensively and didn't find what I was looking for.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: sorry but i dont see the difference: `The resulting value of newString is "This is the string I will be appending to.\F\". I want the value of newString to be "This is the string I will be appending to.\F\".`

Comment: Added code formatting to the strings to highlight the difference.

Comment: Haha. Looks like SO escaped the string for you. SO more powerful than Java. Jk. +1 SO

Comment: How can you tell that the value of `newString` isn't what you're expecting, without using `System.out.println`?  For example, if you're getting that from your IDE's debugger, some IDEs will unescape strings that you're looking at in the debugger...

Comment: Hello Maxim.  Thanks for the reply.  The string I'm getting back upon calling StringBuilder's toString method contains four backslashes(\\F\\) and I only want two backslashes (\F\).

Comment: I'm stupid.  Thanks Louis.  I was watching the debugger values and not the actual value of System.out.println.  Problem solved.

Comment: @user2817193 Now is a good time to click [delete] :-)

Comment: I wouldn't delete it; others may make the same mistake and would benefit from reading this.